# How do I create a DataSet from a parquet?

Tags: dataset, apache-spark-sql

I have the following code to read data from a parquet to Dataframe

```
DataFrame addressDF = sqlContext.read().parquet(addressParquetPath);
```

How do i read data from parquet to DATA SET?

```
Dataset dataset = sqlContext.createDataset(sqlContext.read().parquet(propertyParquetPath).toJavaRDD(), Encoder.);
```

What should the Encoder parameter contain? Also, Do i have to create a property class and then pass that or how is it?

Answer (score 3):

The [Encoder](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Encoder.html) for a type `T` is the class that tells Spark how instances of `T` can be decoded and~ encoded from the internal Spark representation. It contains the schema of the class and the scala [ClassTag](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html) which is used to create your class via reflection.

In your code, you don't specialize Dataset over any type T, so I cannot create an Encoder for you but I can give you as example the one from [Databricks Spark documentation](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/01/04/introducing-apache-spark-datasets.html), which I suggest to read because it is great.
First of all, let's create the class `University` that we want to load into a DateSet:

```
public class University implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private long numStudents;
    private long yearFounded;

    public void setName(String name) {...}
    public String getName() {...}
    public void setNumStudents(long numStudents) {...}
    public long getNumStudents() {...}
    public void setYearFounded(long yearFounded) {...}
    public long getYearFounded() {...}
}
```

Now, `University` is a [Java Bean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans) and the Spark `Encoders` library provides a way to create encoders for Java Beans with the function [bean](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Encoders.html#bean(java.lang.Class)):

```
Encoder<University> universityEncoder = Encoders.bean(University.class)
```

which can then be used to read a Dataset of `University` from parquet without first loading them into a DataFrame (which is redundant):

```
Dataset<University> schools = context.read().json("/schools.json").as(universityEncoder);
```

and now `schools` is a `Dataset<University>` read from a parquet file.